# Unsolved maven property while trying to obfuscate with yGuard

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, obfuscation, yguard

I recently found yGuard and now im trying to obfuscate my project with it, but im having an error while trying to package my jar, here is my plugin configuration on maven pom.xml:

```
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <id>obfuscate</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <property name="runtime_classpath" refid="maven.runtime.classpath"/>
                                <taskdef name="yguard" classname="com.yworks.yguard.YGuardTask" classpath="${runtime_classpath}"/>
                                <yguard>
                                    <inoutpair in="NatchTempfly-1.0.jar" out="NatchTempFly-obf.jar" />
                                </yguard>
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

When I try to package there is an error: "Unsolved maven property maven.runtime.classpath". How can I solve that? I already restarted my IDE, reloaded Maven and all possible things.

All possibilities that I have imagine, nothing solved my problem

Comment: Which version of Maven are you using? How do you execute Maven? What happens if you run `mvn package` in the `examples/application` directory of your yGuard installation directory?

Comment: According to [antrun plugin documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/examples/classpaths.html) `maven.runtime.classpath` is one of the predefined paths for the plugin.